# Applescript: select (highlights) a file in the finder windows after being created by applescript

Tags: file, applescript

I recently switch from windows 7. I am a (very) debutant in applescript.
To create a new file via a hotkey and display dialog, I use spark and the following script i partially found:

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set the this_folder ¬
        to (folder of the front window) as alias
on error -- Merci d ouvrir un dossier avec votre finder
    set the this_folder to path to desktop folder as alias
end try

activate
set thefilename to text returned of (display dialog ¬
"Create file named:" default answer "filename.txt")
set thefullpath to POSIX path of this_folder & thefilename
do shell script "touch \"" & thefullpath & "\""

activate application "Finder"
```

I understand what it does (except shell script touch).
I succeed to place front the display dialog when required, and after entering `thefilename`, the finder window `this_folder`.

I am now trying to select/highlights the newly created file (in order to locate it easily in a long list). I find the code `open -R` which is probably what I am looking for, and try to apply this at the bottom:

```
open -R thefilename
```

and

```
open -R this_folder/thefilename
```

I try to reuse the variable `thefilename` which is the name I entered previously, unsuccessfully.
I don't know how specify the file the open command may reveal.

I apologize if my english is not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set the this_folder ¬
        to (folder of the front window) as alias
on error -- Merci d ouvrir un dossier avec votre finder
    set the this_folder to path to desktop folder as alias
end try


set thefilename to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Create file named:" default answer "filename.txt")

tell application "Finder"
    set thefullpath to make new file at folder this_folder with properties {name:thefilename}
    select thefullpath
end tell
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i just ad "activate" before the second and third paragraphs!